# In Entity Framework EntityState.Detached makes operation slow

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6, query-performance

While debugging below code I found that forEach is taking significant amount of time, for changing state of 6000 records from `EntityState.Unchanged` to `EntityState.Detached` it takes around 16 mins on my local development environment.

The **'where'** expression is filterting the records and **'update'** expression is only updating a single column.

I tried to set ProxyCreationEnabled and LazyLoadingEnabled to false, and it is still taking the same time. What is wrong with this code?

```
DbSet = Context.Set<T>();
...
...
public virtual int UpdateDB(Expression<Func<T, T>> update, Expression<Func<T, bool>> where)
        {
                    var recordsUpdated = DbSet.Where(where).Update(update);
                    foreach (var e in DbSet.Where(where))
                    {
                        var state = Context.Entry(e).State;
                        Context.Entry(e).State = EntityState.Detached;
                        state = Context.Entry(e).State;
                    }
                    return recordsUpdated;                
            }

        }
```

Comment: What exactly happens in this Update method? I suspect you call `SaveChanges` there and have some static context that you try to "reset". That's a couple of bad practices combined.

Comment: @GertArnold in this code we are trying to update the DbSet directly using where and update expressions. What I found ```var recordsUpdated = DbSet.Where(where).Update(update);``` line gets executed quite fast, however line ```Context.Entry(e).State = EntityState.Detached;``` seems to be taking more time looping every record, here we are trying to change state from Unchanged to Detached.

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question. I'm trying to find out why you're doing what you're doing. You shouldn't need to set the state to detached. It probably keeps the change tracker very busy (calling DetectChanges all the time in a bloated context). You should simply dispose the context. This kind of updates, *if* done with EF, should be done by creating stub entities.

Comment: @GertArnold sorry for the confusion I am quite new to the EF world. I am trying to detach the entity so that EF don't track it, but that looks like very bad idea as it is keeping change tracker busy. I will read more on disposing the context. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> What is wrong with this code?

That code is expensive and makes no sense.

This

```
var recordsUpdated = DbSet.Where(where).Update(update);
```

appears to be fetching every row from the database and running through the `Update` function.  Then this

```
foreach (var e in DbSet.Where(where))
```

is fetching every row from the database *again*, but matching them all against the tracked entities, and returning the tracked entity, not the one it just fetched from the database.  The the entity's entry's state is flipped to detached and back to whatever it was before.

What are you trying to acomplish?

If you want to update every row in a table, use SQL directly.  Don't fetch them all to the client, change them and save them back.